# How can I get a list of repositories 'apt-get' is checking?

Tags: apt

I want a list of repositories in *sources.list*, plus those in *sources.list.d/*.

Can I get this list in a form suitable for setting up
another host so it watches the same repositories?

Additionally, how do I determine which repository is the
source of a package, either installed or available?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/148932/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-repositories-and-ppas-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 210):

It seems the closest is:

```
apt-cache policy
```

Comment: Did someone enhance the output (summarizing urls etc) and want to share his command here?

Comment: @Iony Howbout this : `apt-cache policy | awk '/http.*amd64/{print$2}' | sort -u`

Comment: or like this: ```apt-cache policy  | grep origin | sort -u```

Answer (score 60):

As far as I know, you can't ask `apt` for what their current sources are. However, you can do what you want using shell tools.

Getting a list of repositories:

```
grep -h ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* >> current.repos.list
```

Applying the list:

```
apt-add-repository << current.repos.list
```

Regarding getting the repository from a package (installed or available), this will do the trick:

```
apt-cache policy package_name | grep -m1 http | awk '{ print $2 " " $3 }'
```

However, that will show you the repository of the latest version available of that package, and you may have more repositories for the same package with older versions. Remove all the grep/awk stuff if you want to see the full list.

Comment: simple full list `apt-cache policy |grep http |awk '{print $2 $3}' |sort -u`

Comment: missing a space `apt-cache policy |grep http |awk '{print $2 " " $3}' |sort -u`

Comment: In the command line with grep: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` should be changed to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. As to the reason why, see  https://askubuntu.com/questions/82825/do-files-at-etc-apt-sources-list-d-need-to-have-an-extension-list

Comment: The OP has left the building, so it is up to us to make the corrections.

Comment: These are all great. Thanks... One thing, though... why pipe grep to awk? `... | grep anything | awk '{print}'` can be done thusly ```... | awk '/anything/ {print}'``` -- it's like catting a file to pipe to grep.

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: That won't include the repos from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/, IE those resulting from #apt-add-repository XXX

Comment: `grep -Erh ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list*` should do the trick.

Comment: `grep -Erh '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list*` to exclude the `deb-src` lines.

Answer (score 15):

It's *not* a format suitable for blindly copying to another machine, but users who wish to work out whether they've added a repository yet or not (like I did), you can just do:

```
sudo apt update
```

When `apt` is updating, it outputs a list of repositories it fetches. It seems obvious, but I've just realised what the `GET` URLs are that it spits out.

The following `awk`-based expression could be used to generate a *sources.list* file:

```
 cat /tmp/apt-update.txt | awk '/http/ { gsub("/", " ", $3); gsub("^\s\*$", "main", $3); printf("deb "); if($4 ~ "^[a-z0-9]$") printf("[arch=" $4 "] "); print($2 " " $3) }' | sort | uniq
```

Alternatively, as other answers suggest, you could just `cat` all the pre-existing sources like this:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Since the disabled repositories are commented out with hash, this should work as intended.

Comment: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep -e ^[^#]` removes comment lines from output.

Answer (score -7):

All I needed was:

```
cd /etc/apt
nano source.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
apt upgrade && update
```

Source: *[Kali Network Repositories (/etc/apt/sources.list)](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)*